# What does "./bin/www" do in Express 4.x?

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, express

I just started to learn about Express 4.0 in my Node.js app, and I found that it generated `./bin/www` file, on which only the application server and port settings are written and everything others like middleware and routing is defined in `./app.js` file.

However, I'm not sure what this `./bin/www` does. I've used Express 3.x and I have always defined server and port settings as well as routing and middleware on the identical `./app.js` file, and launched my node app with `node app.js`. So what's the point of using the `./bin/www`? Does it only separate the server and port definition from others?

Right now, when I create the package using express-generator, the `package.json` includes the following definition:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
}
```

However, I wonder whether I should launch my app using `node ./bin/www`, or `npm start`. Which command should I run to start my app?

And also, when I deploy my app to heroku, what should I write in the `Procfile` file? Is `web: node app.js` enough?

Comment: See best **Explanation** at https://stackoverflow.com/a/36638353/984471

Comment: It should be noted that `/bin/www` is specific to the `express-generator` tool. From the [express docs](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/migrating-4.html#app-gen): "Neither the `bin` directory nor the extensionless `www` file is mandatory for creating an Express app or starting the app."

Answer (score 164, accepted):

In **Express 3.0**, you normally would use `app.configure()` (or `app.use()`) to set up the required middleware you need. Those middleware you specified are bundled together with Express 3.0.

Example:

```
var express = require('express');
var routes = require('./routes');
var user = require('./routes/user');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');

var app = express();

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.compress());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
```

In **Express 4.0** however, all middleware have been removed so that they can be maintained and updated independently from the core Express (except the static middleware), thus they need to be called separately (what you see in `app.js`).

The `bin/` directory serves as a location where you can define your various **startup scripts**. The `www` is an example to start the express app as a web server.

Ultimately, you could have different scripts like `test`, `stop`, or `restart`, etc. Having this structure allows you to have different startup configurations, without cramming everything into `app.js`.

The correct way to start your Express app is:

```
npm start
```

To deploy an **Express 4.x** app to **Heroku**, add this to your `Procfile`:

```
web: npm start
```

Or if you can just use the start script in your `package.json`, heroku will automatically uses that, read more [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs#specifying-a-start-script)

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www",
}
```

Comment: ... and I'm also having some difficulty making this work on various node / cloud hosting environment

Comment: Thanks. With your excellent explanation on the last two paragraphs, I finally got what's the point of using `www`. I'm not sure why it's named that way though - maybe named after World Wide Web?

Comment: @Ved Where is the document for what you just said about "npm start"? I'd like to study it. Thank you!

Comment: @NicolasS.Xu On the ExpressJS's Github repo https://github.com/visionmedia/express, scroll down to the Quick start section

Comment: @Ved But windows doesn't support shell script.
So it seems it's not very friendly with windows?

Comment: @victorwoo Not sure what you mean, the scripts are just javascripts, runs perfectly fine on Windows.

Comment: @Ved I mean "#!/usr/bin/env node", it seems a linux like path and can't cross platform. It also make JSLint reports error. I think if it's better to separate shell script part and JavaScript part into individual files?

Comment: @victorwoo Yes, if your scripts are platform dependent. I personally think that might be a task for Grunt.js. As for the path, it mostly works on Windows where most of the time developer already installed Git (msysgit), so that is a valid path even on Windows.

Comment: @Ved why "bin", though? I associate that with binary executables.

Comment: @regularmike I guess, it could also means 'executable' scripts (like in the linux's environment)

Comment: @Ved yes, seems like a long time ago it evolved to mean anything executable. Common in Python, Perl, and unix/linux in general.

Comment: you are super saver !! thanks alot :) heroku told everything but not that

Comment: So how can I integrate it to CoffeeScript?

Comment: Hi. I think the bin folder has prevented me from using websocket. Everytime I am trying to do websocket, it doesnt work on herokuapp. It works for localhost only. Any idea how to start websocket and make it works fine on heroku using the express 4?

Comment: not sure if this is specific to nodemon or node 8.11.1 issue  but I had to change mine to `nodemon ./bin/ww.js` including the `.js` extension otherwise it was trying to run as `www index.js`

Comment: @Andy, "what you see in `app.js`"; I'm not sure what this statement means. Perhaps you meant “*from* what you see in `app.js`”?

Comment: @BBaysinger it means what you think it means

Comment: New to Express. So what you're saying is that we should leave bin/www alone and make any changes to app.js (including importing any new dependencies that we install)?  Also, the way npm start in package.json seems to execute bin/www.  How does that in turn execute app.js?

Comment: Interestingly `npm start` does nothing for me.

`package.json`
```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www",
  },
```


Yet, if I do `node ./bin/www` directly it will work and startup the server. :think:

* `npm --version: 6.10.3`
* `node --version: v12.9.1 `
* `express --version: 4.16.1`

Answer (score 12):

Node apps like the Express 3.x  use non-standard startup files `app.js`, but it's the wrong file to run.

`package.json` has

```
   "scripts": {
     "start": "node ./bin/www"
   }
```

which states the startup command line. It’s non-trivial because that potentially contains a full command line, and not just a path to the starter file.

Comment: can you please help me answer this question? Thank you!

Comment: Why is it called bin? It doesn't contain binaries . . .

Comment: For those wondering like Kinnard, this has probably to do with the general use of 'bin' for all things "executable" in unix like OSes and for the reason why unix called it 'bin' [here is an explanation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/370973)

Answer (score 12):

All the above have answered well. 
But in case if you want to use `node app.js` only like Express 3.* versions. You can follow below:

Because the app.js file that was generated by the **Express 4 generator is now a Node.js module**, it can no longer be started independently as an app (unless you modify the code). The module must be loaded in a Node.js file and started via the Node.js file. The Node.js file is ./bin/www in this case. For more info, visit [the official documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/migrating-4.html).

*Neither the bin directory nor the extensionless www file is mandatory for creating an Express app or starting the app. They are just suggestions made by the generator, so feel free to modify them to suit your needs.*

To get rid of the www directory and keep things the “Express 3 way”, delete the line that says module.exports = app; at the end of the app.js file, then paste the following code in its place:

```
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000)

app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
  console.log(`Express server listening on port ${app.get('port')}`);
})
```

Next, change `"start": "node ./bin/www"` in the **package.json** file.
Since, you have now moved the functionality of **./bin/www** back to app.js. Now, start using `"start": "node app.js"` for running your express app.

Answer (score 3):

if you are using express-generator, just look at your local file, there is `www` file inside of the `./bin`. So when you run `node ./bin/www`, node.js will execute the code at `www` file. Nothing fancy.

Comment: and if you are deploying to Azure app service, you have to create web.config and replace all index.js with bin/www , similar to that document https://gist.github.com/rseroter/79ad73f5e6e20b029f765ca8b34f4fad

Answer (score 0):

From the [express docs](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/migrating-4.html#app-gen):

> [...] The actual command that starts the app is `node ./bin/www` [in Express 4], which used to be `node app.js` in Express 3.
> Because the `app.js` file that was generated by the Express 4 generator is now a Node.js module, it can no longer be started independently as an app (unless you modify the code). The module must be loaded in a Node.js file and started via the Node.js file. The Node.js file is `./bin/www` in this case.

Answer (score -1):

put this to Procfile `web: node ./bin/www`
and check if it works with `foreman start`.
The app should be available on port 5000

Answer (score -2):

On Windows, use this command:

> set DEBUG=myapp:* & npm start
>   Then load http://localhost:3000/ in your browser to access the app.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I don't think this really answers the question at hand. Please re-read the question to fully understand all that the Original Poster is asking.