# Express.js - purpose behind ./bin/www

Tags: node.js, express

Simple question:

In regards to Express's generator, what is the purpose and benefit behind abstracting `app.listen()` out of the app.js file and into the `./bin/www` file ?

Comment: Simple but cool, you actually dig out into express stuff and check things out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "./bin/www" do in Express 4.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23169941/what-does-bin-www-do-in-express-4-x)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This makes the app easily testable with [supertest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/supertest), for one thing. This way you can leave your dev server running and still run tests without worrying about TCP port conflicts.