# Learning node.js/express.js: What's the deal with bin/www?

Tags: node.js, express

I've seen tutorials for express.js such as [this](https://youtu.be/6IJu57l_Wuw) which starts from scratch with their own `app.js` file and forgoes using the express generator.

My question: for beginner who's trying to grasp just how to use these tools and make a basic web application should I be concerned with `bin/www` or should I just be defining the port within `app.js`?

The only functionality I currently understand in `bin/www` is setting the port. Is the express generator simply bloated with edge case functionality which is too much for a beginner?

Comment: can go either way. Based on your preferences. I rarely opt for express generator.It's only for application/folder skeleton. I normally create my own folder structure that I comfortable with. Doesn't matter really.

Answer (score 54):

Here is the reason, stated succinctly by an express maintainer:

> So you can require('./app') from external files and get the express
>   app that is not listening on any port (think unit tests and the like).

[source](https://github.com/expressjs/generator/issues/25)

Answer (score 39):

**app.js**

- contains all the middleware(body-parser,morgan,etc) and routes.
- it exports app object at the last.

**www**

- here it creates a httpServer and passes app as the handler

`var server = http.createServer(app);`

- besides also sets the port `server.listen(port);`
- also sets the functions to be called if there is an error while starting the server: `server.on('error', onError);`

**Explanation** so, basically it removes all the create and start server code from your app.js and let you focus only on the application logic part.
**Note:** If you see in `package.json` file you would note this:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node ./bin/www"
}
```

this means if you type in terminal `npm start` then it will automatically start the `./bin/www` file.

Comment: Do you have to add the .bin/www file in your source control?

Comment: @RobbertDraaisma Yes, you have to include it in your source control as it is your entry point.

Comment: @Nivesh If I want to use the server variable in www somewhere else (for example in app.js for socket.io ) how do I access it?

Comment: @Muhannad u can use process.env.VARIABLE_NAME to set environment variables in www.