# Deploying ReactJS production build in Express as HTTPS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, https, certbot

So I am successful when deploying my React app to production server. I am using Express for deploying. Here is my code.

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const port = process.env.PORT || 80
const app = express()

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/build'))

app.get('*', function (request, response){
  response.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'))
})

app.listen(port)
```

I would use CertBot for SSL certs and deploy this as HTTPS server. I really don't know how to approach this problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enabling HTTPS on express.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11744975/enabling-https-on-express-js)

Answer (score 1):

Let's say for example the CertBot generated the SSL certificate and SSL certificate key to the following locations:

- `/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org/fullchain.pem`
- `/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org/privkey.pem`

After you have generated your certificate and key, you'll need to utilize the [`https`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/https.html) module directly.

You'll first need to export your Express app:

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const port = process.env.PORT || 80
const app = express()

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/build'))

app.get('*', function (request, response){
  response.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'))
})

module.export = app
```

Then simply import your Express app and hook it up with the `https` module:

```
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');
const app = require('./app.js');

const server = https.createServer({
  key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org/fullchain.pem', 'utf8'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org/privkey.pem', 'utf8')
}, app);

server.listen(3000);
```

Note this essentially what `./bin/www` does for you except I've adapted it to use `https` instead of `http` module.

See [What does "./bin/www" do in Express 4.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23169941/what-does-bin-www-do-in-express-4-x)

Comment: tls_common.js:88 c.context.setCert(options.cert); - this is the error I get. 
                                             ˇ