# Why use bin/www and not index.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, code-structure, express-generator

The `express-generator` tool creates a file called `bin/www` and uses it as the application's main entry-point. I believe I've seen a couple of other modules do this as well, but the vast majority simply use `index.js`.

What is the rationale behind this? Of course I understand why you would split the server and the code for setting up the program into a separate modules, but why `bin/www` and not `index.js`? Why nest the main-entry point to a program *two* levels deeper than the stuff it *calls*? *And* remove the file-extension, making it even less descriptive?

Is there a clever, non-obvious reason behind this? Should I use this for my node-modules as well?

Thank you!

[edit]:

All good answers, thank you folks! I've accepted the one pointing out that this is standard behaviour for packages that include executables. Here's some more reading I've come across on this:

- https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#bin
- https://blog.npmjs.org/post/118810260230/building-a-simple-command-line-tool-with-npm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're used to running `npm run`, but not sysadmin. He will look for executables (attribute `x`) in the`bin` directory.

The entry point `index.js` is for node module. All packages that provide commands to run on the console contain the `bin` directory.

The extension is removed because it is not a script, but as a program. And these do not have extensions.

Answer (score 4):

*express-generator* create a basic structure for an *express* application. By convention, the entry point of the app is index.js or app.js. In fact, *express-generator* create an app.js at the root of the application with the initial setup of *express*.

Also by convention, the bin/ directory is used for binary files, and by extension for the scripts you can directly launch (note the shebang at the first line of www file). This is common on Linux that binary file has no extension and it could explain the choice to keep this habit for this file.

www, by convention again, is used for naming web application (like /var/www/html in *Apache* server)

Anyway, as the documentation says,

> The app structure created by the generator is just one of many ways to
>   structure Express apps. Feel free to use this structure or modify it
>   to best suit your needs.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23249547/5156280) who talk about the core structure of *express* between version 3 & 4, with the removing of external module.