# What's the purpose of the express.js boilerplate code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm new to Node and Express. And I was just wondering what the significance/use of most of the boilerplate directories that are automatically created when you create an express project.

I've looked online to try to explain the significance of these files and such, and I was just looking for a concise answer and maybe something that somebody who was in my position can look at. The official API doesn't explain the directories, just acknowledges them and shows you how to create them.

```
bin
     www.js
node.modules
     ...
public
     images
     javascripts
     stylesheets
          style.css
routes
     index.js
     users.js
views
     error.jade
     index.jade
     layout.jade
.gitattributes
app.js
package-lock.json
package.json
```

I don't have any questions about node.modules, public, views, .gitattributes, package-lock.json, or package.json. Just wondering what the significance and relation to the rest of the project www.js, index.js, users.js, and app.js are. I know that app.is the "main" entry point for the project, but what is www.js supposed to do? What is users.js and index.js supposed to do? I want to be sure that I'm using these files as intended and as expected by other developers. I appreciate your time.

Comment: FWIW I don't use this directory structure. I use my own with just a main file, a controllers directory, a templates (views) directory and a lib directory for both models and miscellaneous modules. You are free to use your own structure. In the above directory structure bin/www.js is your main file (the executable script of your project).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Express provides this structure in order to encourage developers to structure the code in a good way that can be easily managed and maintained.

Mozilla [express tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/Tutorial_local_library_website)   will answer all your questions mentioned above. It's easy to follow and explains  everything regarding the code structure and good  code practices.

Here is [github](https://github.com/mdn/express-locallibrary-tutorial) of that tutorial were you can check out how everything is impelemented.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23169941/what-does-bin-www-do-in-express-4-x)  is a good SO explanation regarding bin/www .

Comment: i apppreciate it!

Comment: @AlaricJamesHartsock you are welcome, i hope it helps! Consider accepting the answer if it's what you were looking for :)